# Writing to files and \?

Tags: php, html, mathjax

I am trying to write some text to a html file using php. This text contains mathjax and therefore has a lot of \'s in it. However, when I look at the file it creates all the \'s have turned to \\'s and I can't seem to change them back to just single \'s. Any ideas?

For example

```
<?php
$content='$\vec B+\vec C$';
$myfile=fopen('file.html',"w");
fwrite($myfile,$content);
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

Will produce ' $\\vec B+ \\vec C$' in the html file.

Comment: *"Any ideas?"* - any code?

Comment: variables don't get parsed in single quotes if you're getting variables from somewhere. and you need to escape those slashes

Comment: @Fred-ii- what do you mean by 'escape those slashes'?

Comment: @PaulCrovella I don't know mathjax; so... my bad ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php

**Return Values**

Returns a string with backslashes stripped off. (\' becomes ' and so on.) Double backslashes (\\) are made into a single backslash (\).

Comment: Please do not use answers to ask questions. [It's not hard to earn enough rep to make comments.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)

Comment: Note that stripslashes() actually worked, thanks.

Comment: Even though this was the solution, the way it was formed as an answer should've been done differently. Asking questions in an answer is considered as low quality. *Isn't that right Sam?* - @JayBlanchard as per original answer http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/33103181/1 *"stripslashes() maybe ? Does the text come from database or are you writing it on the fly ? http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php"*

Comment: *VLQ Ralph...VLQ.* @Fred-ii-

Comment: Can't emphasize on that enough Sam - @JayBlanchard

Comment: Sorry, first contribution, I didn't read the rules very carefully. I'll try to do better next time.

Comment: I understand. It's all about "quality" Joffrey. Your contribution to Stack is indeed valued, yet Stack was built on a "quality-based" system. Future visitors to the question will benefit on the "reason" why something failed and with an added explanation, helps to keep the guesswork out of things ;-)